# blur no funciona en segundo elemento dinamico (solo en uno) jQuery

Tags: jquery

Resulta que tengo una tabla con un body vacio, la cual es asi:

**TABLA**

```
<table class="table tablaRollo table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Laminas Cortadas</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Largo Laminas m.m.</th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="300px">Total Cortado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
```

Tengo un boton el cual me agrega una nueva fila, cada fila tiene la misma clase mas un contador interno para distinguirlas, por ejemplo cuando agrego la primera fila, esta en un `input` tenda la clase `largo0`, cuando agregue la segunda fila esta tendra la clase `largo1`, y asi sucesivamente.

**AGREGAR NUEVA FILA**

```
    var contador=0;
    var fila=0;
    $('.add-new').on('click', function () {

        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control lamina' + contador + '" name="lamina' + contador + '" id="lamina' + contador + '"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control largo' + contador + '" name="largo' + contador + '" id="largo' + contador + '"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total' + contador + '" name="total' + contador + '" id="total' + contador + '"></td>' +
            +
            '</tr>';
        $(".tablaRollo").append(row);
        fila=contador;
        contador++;

});
```

(`contador` va estableciendo el numero de la fila (0,12,etc), `fila` es igual a contador antes de aumentar esto con el fin de poder obtener el valor de input real)

Resulta que tengo un `blur` que establece cuanto es la multiplicacion de `lamina` y `largo`, y el resultado me lo muestra en `total`

**BLUR**

```
//CUENTE TOTAL CORTADO Y DISMINUYE SALDO
    $(document).on('blur', '.largo' + fila, function () {

        var valor1 = parseInt($('.lamina' + fila).val());
        var valor2 = parseInt($('.largo' + fila).val());

        $('.total' + fila).val(valor1 * valor2);

    });
```

Al generar una nueva fila `contador` vale 1, mientras `fila` vale 0 (como solo hay `largo0`), hasta aqui todo bien. Resulta que al generar una nueva fila otra vez, `contador` valdra 2, y `fila` valdra 1, y va existir un `input` con la clase "`largo1`", a la hora de realizar el truco de `blur`, este no funciona, viene mi pregunta, por que la segunda vez no pasa nada, puesto que todo esta correcto??

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En donde estas colocando el segmento de código de blur?

Comment: @JonathanOrta en un archivo js separado (no se si entendí bien la pregunta, lo siento)

Comment: Como es un archivo separado, las variables no se conocen o bien, solo se va a ejecutar una vez, debe ir en la función de `.add-new`

Comment: @JonathanOrta si, solo se ejecuta una vez, y no entendi lo ultimo, podrias brindarme un ejemplo por que no comprendi bien

Comment: El bloque de código que agrega una nueva fila y el _blur_ están en archivos separados? Si es así, en el archivo del _blur_ está definida la variable `fila`? Sino ahí tenés el problema. Como bien dice @JonathanOrta una opción es poner el código del _blur_ dentro del `$('.add-new')`. Pero lo ideal sería directamente armar el código del _blur_ de otra forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu principal problema radicaba en que al momento de inicializar el documento, estabas seteando la variable *fila* cuando aún no se empezaba a utilizar, por lo tanto siempre sería 0. Y lo segundo, es que no tenías enlazado el evento **[onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)** a algun elemento del `DOM`, o no por lo que pude ver =/

Considerando todo eso, esto podría funcionar

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let contador = 0
  let fila = 0

  $('.add-new').on('click', () => {
  const largo = `largo${contador}`
  const lamina = `lamina${contador}`
  const total = `total${contador}`

  const row = `<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control ${lamina}" name="${lamina}" id="${lamina}"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control ${largo}" name="${largo}" id="${largo}" onblur="setTotal(${contador})"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control ${total}" name="${total}" id="${total}"></td></tr>`

  $(".tablaRollo").append(row)
    //debugger
    fila = contador
    //console.log(fila)
    contador++
  })  
})

function setTotal(fila) {
  //debugger
  const valor1 = parseInt($(`.lamina${fila}`).val())
  const valor2 = parseInt($(`.largo${fila}`).val())

  $(`.total${fila}`).val(valor1 * valor2)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table tablaRollo table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Laminas Cortadas</th>
         <th scope="col">Largo Laminas m.m.</th>
         <th scope="col" width="300px">Total Cortado</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-default add-new">Agregar</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Principalmente le asigne el evento **setTotal** al input de lamina y mejoré un poco la sintaxis basándome en `ECMAScript6` :)

Nos comentas si te sirvió ;)